# Display object[i] from array in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I want to iterate trough an array of objects and display an item in a component, where the prop is the index number of the array item.

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './projecten.scss';
import Layout from './../Layout/Layout';
import { ProjectenLijst } from '../../../data';

const Projecten = () => {
  const ProjectItem = ({i}) => (
    <div>{ProjectenLijst[i]}</div>
  )

  return (
    <Layout>
      <ProjectItem i={2}/> // here I want to set the index number of the array
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default Projecten;
```

And this is the data file I'm pulling the data from:

```
export const ProjectenLijst = [
  {
    naam: 'Project 1',
    id: 1,
    wat: 'website',
    url: 'https://www.project1.com',
    platform: 'WordPress',
    omschrijving: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis blandit magna leo, sit amet bibendum risus tincidunt non. Duis vitae ligula vel felis tincidunt facilisis. Maecenas interdum ligula ut vestibulum scelerisque. Aenean vestibulum ultrices augue. Mauris nec aliquam nulla, quis ultrices arcu. Aliquam fringilla.',
    img: ''
  },

  {
    naam: 'Project 2',
    id: 2,
    wat: 'website',
    url: 'https://www.project2.com',
    platform: 'WordPress',
    omschrijving: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis blandit magna leo, sit amet bibendum risus tincidunt non. Duis vitae ligula vel felis tincidunt facilisis. Maecenas interdum ligula ut vestibulum scelerisque. Aenean vestibulum ultrices augue. Mauris nec aliquam nulla, quis ultrices arcu. Aliquam fringilla.',
    img: ''
  },

  {
    naam: 'Project 3',
    id: 3,
    wat: 'website',
    url: 'https://www.project3.com',
    platform: 'WordPress',
    omschrijving: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis blandit magna leo, sit amet bibendum risus tincidunt non. Duis vitae ligula vel felis tincidunt facilisis. Maecenas interdum ligula ut vestibulum scelerisque. Aenean vestibulum ultrices augue. Mauris nec aliquam nulla, quis ultrices arcu. Aliquam fringilla.',
    img: 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/4873818/pexels-photo-4873818.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500'
  }
];
```

I can't get this to work. The code renders the page, but the part where the project item should render stays empty. I'm overlooking something..but what am I doing wrong? :-)

Thanks!

//Ninja-edit: cleaned the code some more

Comment: Remove the wiggly brackets where you index into the array. One set around the entire expression is enough. You’re not indexing with a number, but instead an object that has a key/value of i.

Comment: Then I get the error:

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {naam, id, wat, url, platform, omschrijving, img}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: The code drastically changed since my comment. You may find a solution to your problem, but i think it's easy to miss the explanation. There seem to be several problems that are shifted around.

Comment: The code didn't drastically changed. I only removed the curly braces from the first (i) call.

Comment: That's quite a drastic change. The first part of the accepted answer no longer seems relevant.

Comment: While your question is somewhat specific to your problem. It helps others who might run into the exact same issue (say following the same tutorial). One of the issues was this "how to index into an array + JS object destructuring" , the current code does not show that, only the other issues. I'd suggest to bring back the moment right before the accepted answer was posted.

Comment: No problem :-) Fixed it.

Comment: Heh, i think you fixed it fixed it, the code may not contain any arrors, the key was in `projectLijst[{i}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems.

1. When you call `ProjectenLijst` using `<ProjectItem i={2} />` you must extract the `i` property by using curly braces:

   ```js
   const ProjectItem = (i) => (/* ... */);
   // should be
   const ProjectItem = ({i}) => (/* ... */);
   ```

   See [Destructuring assignment - Object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)
2. You can't render complex objects, only scalar values. Meaning that:

   ```
   <div>{ProjectenLijst[i]}</div>
   // should for example be
   <div>{ProjectenLijst[i].naam}</div>
   ```

```js
// mock
const Layout = (props) => <div {...props} />;
const ProjectenLijst = [
  { naam: 'Project 1', id: 1 },
  { naam: 'Project 2', id: 2 },
  { naam: 'Project 3', id: 3 },
];

// answer
const Projecten = () => {
  const ProjectItem = ({i}) => (        // extract the "i" property by using curly braces
    <div>{ProjectenLijst[i].naam}</div> // refer to a scalar property, not the whole object
  );

  return (
    <Layout>
      <ProjectItem i={2} />
    </Layout>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Projecten />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import './projecten.scss';
import Layout from './../Layout/Layout';
import { ProjectenLijst } from '../../../data';

const Projecten = () => {
  const ProjectItem = (i) => (
    <div>{ProjectenLijst[i].name}</div>
  )

  return (
    <Layout>
      {ProjectenLijst.map((item, index) => {
         return <ProjectItem i={index}/>
      })}
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default Projecten;
```

or

```
import React from 'react';
import './projecten.scss';
import Layout from './../Layout/Layout';
import { ProjectenLijst } from '../../../data';

const Projecten = () => {
  const ProjectItem = (item) => (
    <div>{item.name}</div>
  )

  return (
    <Layout>
      {ProjectenLijst.map(item => {
         return <ProjectItem item={item}/>
      })}
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I also tried your methods, but that doesn't work either. I don't understand what the issue is here :-)

Comment: @Paul sorry, I've misspelled `name`. It is `naam` in your objects

Comment: It's not that, the issue with this answer is that you don't pass props properly. It should be `item.item.naam` if you want this to work.

Comment: Or `ProjectItem = ({item})=>...`

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on the initial comment, since the code changed:

```
const ProjectItem = ({i}) => (
  <div>{ProjectenLijst[{i}]}</div>
)
```

First, you made a functional component, hence you can call:

```
<ProjectItem i={0} foo="foo" bar="bar">
```

Let's rewrite the the functional component to not destructure the arguments:

```
const ProjectItem = (props)=> {
  console.log(props.i) //0
  console.log(props.foo) //"foo"
  console.log(props.bar) //"bar"
  ...
}
```

Since we only need the `i` prop/key, we can *destructure* this, both the argument:

```
const ProjectItem = ({i})=>{...}
```

Or inside the function, say if we wanted to pass the whole props object to another component:

```
const ProjectItem = (props)=>{
  const {i,foo} = props //to use locally
  const aThing = thingMaker(props)
  ...
}
```

Let's remind ourselves how we index into an array:

```
const i = 0
const someObject = { i: i }
const alternatively = { i } //shorthand to {i:i}

const someArray = [0,1,2,3]

console.log(someArray[ i ]) //0 first element
console.log(someArray[ someObject ]) //i think it will be undefined,
```

Simply you can't index with an object into the array.

Applying all of this into your original snippet, and removing most of the shorthands

```
const ProjectItem = (props)=>{
  // get the index
  const { i } = props          //destructure
  const { i: myIndex } = props //destructure and alias
  const _i = props.i           //same thing no destructuring

  // get the item (use any of these)
  const myItem0 = ProjectenLijst[i]
  const myItem1 = ProjectenLijst[props.i]
  const myItem2 = ProjectenLijst[myIndex]
  const myItem3 = ProjectenLijst[_i]

  //JSX

  return <div> 
   { myItem0 } 
  </div> 
 
}
```

Notice the `{ myItem0 }` you have one set of braces `{}` and a variable in between.

So to recap, what you were doing with:

```
const ProjectItem = ({i}) => (
  <div>{ProjectenLijst[{i}]}</div>
)
```

is:

```
const ProjectItem = (props)=> {
  const someArbitraryObject = { i: props.i }
  const item = ProjectenLijst[ someArbitraryObject ]

  console.log(someArbitraryObject) // { i: 0 }
  console.log(item) // undefined

  return <div>{item}</div>
}
```

This was just one of the issues with the original code - *indexing into arrays* and *destructuring*.
Other answers about what can be rendered with JSX etc. also apply.

Comment: Thanks! This really helps understanding the structures <3